# Upload image from subdomain to another subdomain folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have 1 domain with 2 sub domain :

mainweb.com, img.mainweb.com and adm.mainweb.com. The root folder then seem like this :

```
img (folder & subdomain)
adm (folder & subdomain)
upload_image.php
```

I have no problem to upload image using upload_image.php here, because this file is in the mainweb root.

upload_image.php :

```
$dir = 'img/';

$upload->UploadImageFile($dir);
```

Problem : How I define directory path if I am working inside subdomain adm.mainweb.com? Meaning if the upload_image.php file is inside this adm.mainweb.com? I have tried to do this but not working. Maybe cross domain issue.

adm/upload_image.php :

```
$path = 'http://img.mainweb.com';
$dir = $path.'/img/';

$upload->UploadImageFile($dir);
```

is any htaccess required?

Comment: `../img/` should work

Comment: @ hjpotter92 That's the way I did from main domain. Problem if from sub to sub or from sub to main domain.

Comment: I'm assuming these sub domains are all on the same server ?? Did you try using an absolute path such as '/home/mysite/adm' ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have the solution for this problem. At least it works on my localhost but not yet tested on live server.

I do upload image inside subdomain adm.mainweb.com like normally in a folder (expl : adm.mainweb.com/images/. And at the end of the php upload file, I try to call a php file in the mainweb.com to :

1. Move the image file from folder inside subdomain adm.mainweb.com to  img.mainweb.com. Because for main domain, subdomain can be supposed like a folder rather than only domain.
2. Delete the source file.

The illustration of the calling php file is :

```
header('Location:http://mainweb.com.com/move_image.php?image='.$img.'&folder='.$folder');
```

and the move_image.php in main domain :

```
$source = $_GET['image'];  $dest = $_GET['folder'];
copy($source, $dest);
unlink($source);
```

Now, when administrator upload an image (inside secure page of adm.mainweb.com) to a folder, all image file then moved directly to img.mainweb.com folder, no cross domain issue.

When people browse the main domain, all images is loaded from img.mainweb.com. it meets the most issues that images should be loaded from other domain to speed up loading.

I hope this will help. Any commands for better and secure ways is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you are making it so complex. Adding "../" is just what was needed.
I have tried it on a live server.

I uploaded from one subdomain to another subdomain with the path as "../another.subdomain.com/assets/img/booksImages/" and it works like charm.